# Showing or saving intermediate image tensor in keras

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to debug a custom loss function and I would like to visualize the images generated during the intermediate computation step in the objective function. A tf_summary_image or a simple imshow would be perfect, but the summary it is not working without calling a sess.run() with a proper feed_dict. For simplicity, let's say I have:

```
def custom_objective(y_pred, y_true):
    diff = y_pred - y_true
    #Here I would need something to save and/or show the diff image
    square = K.square(diff)
    #Here I would need something to save and/or show the square image
    mean = K.mean(square, axis=-1)
    return mean
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post the errors you get when running the model with your custom loss?

Comment: I am not getting errors, I only would like to analyze some intermediate output because my loss does not decrease, so I'd like to see if there is something wrong in the computations